# How to connect both inputs of a nand gate to a same node?

Tags: circuitikz, node-connections, circuits

Hi im trying to connect both inputs of a logic gate, to a batterry connected to ground. Im having a problem finding the information about the sintaxis of the logic gates, i have read the documentation of circuitikz but there is no information of the available anchors, or the ways to connect the pins of the gate(straight lines, curve lines, something...). Also i am having problem understanding how to declare nodes to connect the gate.

Maybe i miss some information...

```
\begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to [battery] (0,1)
            (3,1) node[nand port] (nand1){}
            (nand1.in 2) 
            (nand1.in 1) ;          
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

I have achieve this, but looks ugly...

```
\begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to [battery] (0,1)
            (3,1) node[nand port] (nand1){}
            (nand1.in 2) -- (nand1.in 1) 
            (nand1.in 1) -- (0,1);          
    \end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

For example i dont know what are the --, or how to declare nodes to connect and how to properly connect both inputs and the nodes created with another nodes.
Thanks a lot for the information.(:

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far, and perhaps an screenshot marked with the changing you want to have.  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

With your MWE you was quit cole to above image, only one coordinate I change (actually I increase all vertical distances):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0) node[ground]{} to [battery] (0,1.5)
        (3,1.5) node[nand port] (nand1){}
        (nand1.in 1) -- (nand1.in 2)
        (nand1.in 1 |- nand1.out) to [short,*-] (0,1.5);% changed coordinate of line
                                                        % between battery and gate
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```